# ElasticSearch [term] query doesn't support multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following data structure in ElasticSearch:

```
"assets": {
     "type": "nested",
     "properties": {
         "assetId": {
             "type": "keyword"
         },
         "assetSource": {
             "type": "keyword"
         },
}
```

Say I want to exclude the result that 'assetSource' has value 'Web'

I used `Term(field='assets.assetSource', query='web')` in the `query.exclude`, but since assets is multi-field, it complains `[term] query doesn't support multiple fields`

How do I work around this problem?

Comment: My guess is that I can use 'match' since it's 'keyword' type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me, I should have used the Term filter like this:

```
Term(**{'assets.assetSource':'vault'})
```